# Cannot Assign Void to an Implicitly-Typed Variable MVC 5

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I am receveing the error "Cannot Assign Void to an Implicitly-Typed Variable"for model.Password here:

`var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);`

on the

`ExternalLoginConfirmation` and `Register` classes of the `AccountController.cs` file in my project.

If I remove `model.Password` parameter from the code everything works fine, but I a cannot pass a password as parameter. I have no idea how to fix this.

I have been working on a project for 2 weeks and it would be a huge setback to have to redo everything, is there a way that I can fix this? Thank you

Comment: Are you asking how to recover your deleted passwords or do you just want to make the code work?

Comment: I don't need to recover user passwords, I just need to restore the actual column and not have the model.Password return void.

Comment: it appears `CreateAsync` is just returning `Task`, no return value.

Comment: @Vsno99 add the Password property back to the entity class. delete all existing migrations. create a new migration from scratch. it should work fine.

Comment: The technical thing would be to create user without passing password, then check if it was successfully created if yes, then Create Password for the user.